# Which is the best way to manipulate data/sheet of an excel document in C#

Tags: c#, excel, forms, vba

I'm currently busy with a task that involves both manipulating data in an excising excel document as well as the sheet itself.

In the past I've always used OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand to work with excel, but I've been reading about something called a Workbook and I'm not sure which way I should go about this.

Some examples of what I need to do include-

1. Inserting a new column
2. Deleting old columns
3. Setting a cell a certain colour depending on it's contents
4. Looking for duplicates and deleting them.

In your option which way would be the most efficient way to go about this.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look in EPPlus, there is even a documentation section here in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/topics

Comment: PIA, if you ask for best, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way would be to go with `excel interop` if you don't want to use any third party library.

`Interop` works and any action can be performed which you have mentioned in your question.

Refer this link for more info: http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-tutorial.htm

PS: `above link is for c# and for interop to work ms excel must be installed on the system, this can be implemented in vb.net as well.`

Hope this helps.

Comment: `interop` will be able to do anything Excel does, but you have to have Excel instaled and it is slower than other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Visual Studio Tools for Office, you will have workbooks, worksheets, columns, ranges, etc. Easy to manipulate using C#.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608603.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Install this package into your project  Further no need to install Excel also this is fast mothod https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/